# Prevent Refreshing parent page when closing child page before full loading

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

When I open child page using window.open() method. and before fully loading of child page when I close this it will refresh parent page in  "ie-11" . I want to stop refreshing parent page. 
Thanks in advance.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Page Title</title>
</head>
<body>

<button onclick="openWindow()">
  OpenWindow
</button>

<script>
function openWindow(){
window.open(url, "_blank","height=200,width=200,status=1,toolbar=1,location=no,scrollbars=yes");
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You can't. The browser will prevent you from interfering in this case. The only terribly hacky thing you could do is alert something which would prevent the refresh until the alert is dismissed but if you do this you are a terrible person.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
function openWindow(e){
```

e.preventDefault();
window.open(url, "_blank","height=200,width=200,status=1,toolbar=1,location=no,scrollbars=yes");

}

Comment: That won't do anything in this case.

Comment: That's unfortunate.